# how to show variable in Spyder Variable explore while debugging?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Spyder Variable explore only show variables when i run a python script. But while debugging, there is nothing in Spyder Variable explore.
how to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Spyder **3.2**, which was released in July of 2017.

Comment: Really? I can't seem to see my class objects.

Comment: I was not talking about class objects, I was talking about inspecting the contents of any object but while debugging.