# How to view class objects in Spyder's variable explorer

Tags: anaconda, spyder

This is a repeat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546031/how-to-show-variable-in-spyder-variable-explore-while-debugging) question. It seems that I can't view instances of my classes in the variable explorer in Python, when I'm debugging.

There the answer claims that this is resolved, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) By default we show builtins (ints, floats, strings, list, dicts and tuples), Numpy arrays and Dataframes in our Variable Explorer.

If you want to see all objects present in your namespace, you need to go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Variable Explorer`

and turn off the option called

`Exclude unsupported data types`

Comment: I'm having this issue where I can't watch my class member variables update as I'm debugging. In the variable explorer, I see my class instance, but I can't see any of the member variables. If I double-click on it, it will give me a snapshot of the member variables, but it will not update as the code executes, so I have to double click every time if I want to see what's changed.

Comment: That's a limitation of our current design, but it's not an easy one to solve. All variable explorer viewers show a copy of the inspected object because code is evaluated in a separate process called kernel. So when you want to inspect an object, we ask the kernel to send a copy of it so Spyder can display it. What we could do is adding an *Update* button so users can manually update an open viewer.