# Debugging in Python: IDE that shows you class instances live update

Tags: python, class, debugging, ide

Recently I was debugging some code in Python. As I stepped through my lines of code, I kept my eye on the variable explorer in my IDE (Spyder). I noticed that when it came to looking at instances of a class I had created, the variable explorer was poor. It wouldn't show me the values of member variables as I stepped through my code. I could double click on my class instance and see the values of the member variables, but they would stay static, making it useless. I would have had to double click on the instance every time I wanted to see if anything had changed. (I wrote a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634481/how-to-view-class-objects-in-spyders-variable-explorer/50634853?noredirect=1#comment88313295_50634853).)

When I was programming in c++, xCode had the capability to show you the class instance and all its members, updating live, from the variable explorer. I wonder if there's an IDE that does this for Python. (Perhaps xCode itself?) I use Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’ve understood you correctly, you want to evaluate members dynamically as code gets executed. Ie watch data structures change when changed. The vs code IDE is what I use for python development and it supports the common idea of adding “watch” variables that allow you to do what you are wanting.

This is VS code:
https://code.visualstudio.com

Here is an article for getting started with python on vscode:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

And another with specific screenshots and debugging examples showcasing the feature:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

And another only about debugging details:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: VS Code looks awesome! Thanks

Comment: No problem! Its a great editor that support other languages as well.